# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps;

Tags: scala, maven, jersey, swagger

I'm running into an error here and it's some sort of conflict with my dependencies.  I thought looking at hte source would provide a clue, so I went to `org.fusesource.scalate.jersey.ScalateTemplateProcessor` which brought me to http://scalate.fusesource.org/maven/1.3/scalate-core/scaladocs/org/fusesource/scalate/jersey/ScalateTemplateProcessor.html.  I was hoping to find something in this class that helped me understand what `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps;` was referring to.  Unfortunately I'm still very confused as to what's actually happening here.

**What class is `scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps;` referring to?**

```
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17.1 02/28/2013 12:47 PM'
Sep 17, 2013 8:54:40 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Adding the following classes declared in META-INF/services/jersey-server-components to the resource configuration:
  class org.fusesource.scalate.rest.NodeWriter
  class org.fusesource.scalate.rest.TransformerWriter
  class org.fusesource.scalate.rest.ViewWriter
  class org.fusesource.scalate.jersey.ScalateTemplateProcessor
  class org.fusesource.scalate.jersey.ScalateTemplateProvider
Sep 17, 2013 8:54:40 AM com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory __getComponentProvider
SEVERE: The provider class, class org.fusesource.scalate.jersey.ScalateTemplateProcessor, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps;
    at org.fusesource.scalate.util.Log$.apply(Logging.scala:33)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine$.<init>(TemplateEngine.scala:42)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine$.<clinit>(TemplateEngine.scala)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.servlet.ServletHelper$.errorUris(ServletHelper.scala:30)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.jersey.ScalateTemplateProcessor.<init>(ScalateTemplateProcessor.scala:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:209)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:179)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:166)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory._getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:159)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:131)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:256)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProvidersAndServices(ProviderServices.java:173)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.TemplateFactory.<init>(TemplateFactory.java:63)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1166)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:774)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:172)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyServerFactory.java:242)
    at com.production.api.Main.startServer(Main.java:34)
    at com.production.api.Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

My **pom.xml**

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-http-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.23</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate/Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>management</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You are likely have multiple major versions of scala that comes as transitive dependencies. Issue `mvn dependency:tree | grep scala` and hopefully you will see them.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I'm on Windows using IntelliJ.  I'm unfamiliar with what a transitive dependency is.  :goes to Google it:

Comment: @om-nom-nom Looking at the dependency tree, my jackson library and swagger codegen both use `scala-library` v 2.9, whereas other dependencies use 2.10

Comment: well, many maven libraries have a concept of transitive dependencies: when you add library as a dependency it will say *hey I'm foo and my friends are bar and baz*. For example, if you add your project as a dependency to some other project you will have dependencies enlisted under <dependencies> as your friends -- they are not explicitly invited into the party, but they come with you. The problem with your config that some of libraries above ask different versions of scala, and maven will pick only one, leaving some of the invited dependencies unsatisfied.

Comment: Solution is to move jackson and swagger to versions [built against 2.10](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.10/2.1.3) or move everything else to versions built against 2.9. I don't see swagger artifact for 2.10, but I've done only a shallow search. If there is no one, you could compile it by yourself or back to all-2.9-plan. By the way, such problem comes only with the major scala releases (2.8 -> 2.9 -> 2.10), minor ones (2.9.1 -> 2.9.2 -> 2.9.3) are binary compatible and have no such problem.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Thanks for the breakdown... this is confusing since I've never done it before, but I'm gonna see what I can do.

Comment: looks like [swagger **was** built against 2.10](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/wordnik/) so the easiest way to move everything to 2.10.

Comment: This appears to be a black hole of dependency issues, so I'm just going to avoid swagger.  Thanks!